# How to call parent's parent javascript function from child window

Tags: javascript

How to call parent's parent javascript function from child window.

Example-
Parent 1 has javascript function abc()
Now how to call Parent1 Javascript function in Child window from Parent 2 which is initially trigged from Parent 1 Window.
I tried window.parent.parent. Still no luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you mean with a child window. But I guess [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener) might be what you are looking for.

```
// Call abc in the window that opened the current window
window.opener.abc();
```

**Update**

Haven't tried it, but since `window.opener` is a reference to the window that opened the current window, then I guess you should be able to call the `opener` property on that reference, to get a reference to the its parent as well:

```
window.opener.opener.abc();
```

If you want to reach the topmost window (the root window, or what you would call it), then you can use [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top) instead:

```
window.top.abc();
```

Comment: Yes I agree this works fine when we open child window from immediate parent window.But in my case i have one page1 from which i call one more page2 from this i call child window.Now my requirement is to call page1 javascript function from child window.

Comment: @Beginner Updated my answer with some additional info.

Comment: Still no luck it says undefined but if call window.opener in Page2(child page) from Page1 it works fine but in child window from Page2 it says undefined :(